# Forced logout when i run a docker container

Tags: docker, fedora

When i run a new docker container (or when i start a stopped one), the system logs me out. When i login again the container is up 'n running and i can use it without any problems.

I am currently using Fedora 24.

Example:

```
alekos@alekos-pc:~$ docker run -d --name somename -t -p 80:80 someimage
```

> At this point it logs me out

When I log in again I run:

```
alekos@alekos-pc:~$ docker ps -a
```

and my "somename" container is running without any further problems.

I can live with these logouts/logins but it is a bit annoying. Does anybody have any idea what is causing the problem?

Comment: what do you mean "logs you out" -- of the container? or your OS?

Comment: It logs me out of the OS. It throws me back to the login prompt.

Comment: After updating to Fedora 27, the problem seems to exist no more...